# Having data virtualization in Unity3d UI panel

Tags: unity-game-engine, panel

I have a UIpanel in my application and i instantiate gameobject in it programmatically during runtime, the problem i have is i have to create more than 1000 gameobjects (sometimes up to 6000) in that panel and that takes a long time freezing the UI and trying it with Coroutines cause some lags as well.
is there any way to have a list of gameobjects and create them in UI panel during user scrolling that panel?
or can somebody suggest a better way of adding gameobjects to a panel without any lag or UI freeze?

**UPDATE :**
I added this to clear my goal.
i have a long list of items that i trying to put them in a list each item have a picture a some button and some texts, below there is a sample from a single item:

[image: example of single item]

now i need to instantiate this complex sample in a panel and each item change itself based on a ID i pass after instantiation.
but i have a panel capacity problem and even if i cut some item when i put that many object in a panel at once scrolling in panel make it very slow and painful
also i need a scroll bar for my panel so i have to have all of my object available in the panel

hope this information helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you describe it that way, its much clearer & much simpler.

Look at any mobile application: they do not put 6000 people records on a single page.  Its normally paged or grouped, with a search option. So do that instead.

If you look at the facebook mobile app (a good standard) if you start scrolling to look at older posts, every few seconds it pauses for a second or two to load the next few posts. Its the same with the youtube app.

Because of this 65535 unity limit, just put in a paging limit (say 100-200 items).

Comment: but if i use pages how can i implement scroll bar? and i need to add letters on the side (just like contacts app) in order to jump to that letter if someone hits them

Comment: http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui there is some good stuff on creating scrollbars & dynamic creation UI at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just wrote a test program which generated 1000 Text UI elements.

```
public class MakeLoadsOfUI : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject prefab;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        MakeUI();

    }

    void MakeUI()
    {
        float startTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            int x=i/40, y=i%40;

            GameObject obj = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab);
            obj.transform.SetParent(transform);   // attack to the canvas
            RectTransform rt = obj.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
            rt.anchoredPosition = new Vector2((x-10)*25, (y-10)*20);
            obj.GetComponent<Text>().text = "UI:" + i;
        }
        float endTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
        Debug.Log("time taken:" + (endTime - startTime));
    }
}
```

It took 0.15 seconds for 1000 elements which was quite reasonable.  If you had a different result please elaborate, explaining how you did it.

Comment: UIText is quite trivial. If you instantiate complexer objects it will load longer...  1000 is indeed much for a list.  you could try pooling the objects and just  load them when they are displayed. => Instantiate X empty "Cells" and fill them (asynchron => coroutine) with Content when they are onscreen.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Mark but sometimes i'm instantiate nearly 6000 gameobject that have at least 12 child each it takes a long time but worst of all sometimes canvas capacity gave out (not more than 65535 vertices) or if i can put that many in canvas 6000 available gameobject at once make application nearly useless and frozen all the time. i really need a way to visualize these objects so they weren't all be in the scene at once.

Comment: @MariusJunak i tried your theory but even 6000 empty gameobject make application slow and useless

Comment: Just tested 6000 objects, 1.5 seconds, but the item canvas refused to go over 65535 vertices & errors. 
If you want 6000 x 12 items its going to be crazy complex.
I think you might want to start a new question explaining what you are trying to get, there might be another way to approach the problem.

Comment: the main problem isn't time i can wait for 2 seconds. the problem is my app should run on phones and having this many object at the same time in a scene causes awful application speed and many lag.

Comment: I updated my question to be more clear on what i'm trying to do.

Comment: You could just instantiate the Objects you need and throw the rest away or make an object pool wich reuses the objects.  For example, if you can display 10 Items in your panel. Instantiate items 0 - 20 => if you scroll down 5 items => throw away 0-5 and instantiate 21-25.

Comment: that could work but consider that i need scroll bar for the list and if i don't have all of my items in the panel then scroll bar doesn't work properly.